# como leer un archivo delimitado por comas en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo un archivo de texto de enteros el cual necesito obtener cada número completo que esta separado por comas. Sé que con espacios el compilador sabe que son cosas distintas, pero ¿cómo lo puedo hacer si son comas?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `std::getline` y `std::stringstream`:

```
std::string linea;
while(std::getline(fichero,linea))
{
    std::stringstream   stream(linea);
    std::string         valor;

    std::cout << "Contenido de la linea:\n";
    while(std::getline(stream,valor,','))
    {
        std::cout << "valor leido: " << valor << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "Fin de la linea\n";
}
```

Para futuras preguntas por favor, pon código que muestre dónde te estás estancando.